# Webcam not working on Ubuntu

Tags: webcam

I have a Papalook PA452 webcam that I'm trying to use with Ubuntu 18.04. I'm not sure if it will work on Linux (the instructions only talk about Windows and Mac). It's plug and play for Windows and Mac, but when I use `Cheese` it doesn't seem to recognise the webcam.

I'm not sure what to do next. Do I need to find and install some drivers perhaps?

Thank you.

---

When my cam is in, the  last lines of the output of `dmesg`:

```
[ 1838.157679] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 1838.482687] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=58b0
[ 1838.482689] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1838.482690] usb 1-3: Product: Full HD webcam
[ 1838.482691] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: SHENZHEN AONI ELECTRONIC CO.,LTD
[ 1838.482692] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 20200306001
[ 1838.754977] usb 1-3: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[ 1838.754982] usb 1-3: [5] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[ 1933.845909] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1959.673098] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 1960.001778] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=58b0
[ 1960.001785] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1960.001790] usb 1-3: Product: Full HD webcam
[ 1960.001794] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: SHENZHEN AONI ELECTRONIC CO.,LTD
[ 1960.001797] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 20200306001
[ 1960.274871] usb 1-3: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[ 1960.274885] usb 1-3: [5] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
```

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer is **NO**

As you mentioned earlier, the user manual only mentions that it works only on certain OSs:

> Windows XP/7/8/10 or later, Mac OS 10.6 or later, Chrome OSTM, Android v5.0 or above

from [Papalook PA452 - User's Manual - Page EN-6](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0049/7480/5056/files/papalook_PA452_PRO_User_Manual.pdf?3750)

But looking for an answer for you i found [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) Question on AskUbuntu mentions some ways to make your device work on your OS

- [Integrated webcam not detected after update to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04)
- [Webcam (Ubuntu Community Wiki)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam)
- [UVC driver homepage](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/)has a list of all officially supported webcam models by this one universal driver.

Hope this helps!